# Centering and spacing of multiline cells in tabu does not seem to work

Tags: tabu

The tabu environment does not seem to center the text in cells with multiple lines correctly. At the same time, the spacing seems to be erroneous.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? I have tried \makecell[tc]{sensor \ molecule} but this does seem to create other problems.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {*6{X[c]}}
    \tabucline{-}
    sensor\newline molecule & position & chemical~shift\newline reference & some &  other &info \\
    \tabucline{-}
    xyz & C$_1$ & aaa & 1.11 &  3.54 & 11.00 \\
    xyz & C$_5$ & bbb & 2.22 & 44.54 & 12.0 \\
    \tabucline{-}
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: table created with tabu which does not center text in cells with multiple lines correctly]

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Which package are you using to make the `\makecell` command available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this better?

[image]

just add `\tabulinesep=_3pt^3pt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % <-- added
\usepackage{tabu}
\tabulinesep=_3pt^3pt% <-- added

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {*6{X[c]}}
    \tabucline{-}
    sensor molecule & position & chemical shift reference & some &  other &info \\
    \tabucline{-}
    xyz & C$_1$ & aaa & 1.11 &  3.54 & 11.00 \\
    xyz & C$_5$ & bbb & 2.22 & 44.54 & 12.0 \\
    \tabucline{-}
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Off topic: in your table is not need to manually break cell contents, this will done by column type `X`, if necessary.

**Edit:**
Source of not centering third column header is to wide content. If you make `\textwidth` longer, for example with adding of package `geometry`, the content will become correctly centered.

**Addendum:**
Less problems is with `tabularx` and use `booktabs` for table's rules. With `siunitx` you can align numbers at decimal points. For equal width of all columns is used trick with `multicolumn` environment for `S` column headers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}{C}
                             *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]}}
    \toprule
sensor molecule & position & chemical~shift reference 
    & \mcx{some} & \mcx{other} & \mcx{info} \\

    \midrule
    xyz & C$_1$ & aaa & 1.11 &  3.54 & 11.00 \\
    xyz & C$_5$ & bbb & 2.22 & 44.54 & 12.0 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this already looks better in the cell containing "sensor molecule". However, the cell containing "chemical shift reference" is still misaligned. Thank you for the off topic comment, you were off course right in this case. How do I solve the problem in the other cell and how is tabulinesep related to centering text in cells? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user4834588, why you use `tabu`? This packae is not maintained and buggy ... less problems you will have for example with `tabularx`.  from `tabu` documentation follows, that `tabulinesep` hadn't have influence to node aligns. See addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I just now noticed that you are missing the line `\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}`if I am not mistaken, otherwise, the comand `mcx`is not recognized.

Comment: Thank you for edit my answer! At loading code I accidentally erase wrong line of code or forgot to add it :( .